# How to use mopidy-youtube?

Tags: arch-linux, mpd, music-player, bspwm

I am using Arch bspwm on my laptop. I installed `mpd`, `ncmpcpp` and `mopidy` (with mopidy-yt extension) and enabled the required stuff for mopidy-youtube. How do I use it? I am new to all this and hope you guys can explain.

Answer (score 1):

Like said in the [readme of the mopidy-youtube repository](https://github.com/natumbri/mopidy-youtube), you have to open your MPD client, ncmpcpp for instance, and type the following command:

`yt:<youtube link here>`

But first, make sure you enabled mopidy-youtube correctly by going to your MPD configuration file and add if needed:

```
[youtube]
enabled = true
```

For instance, if you want to listen to Purple by Roa:

`yt:https://youtu.be/7PR3I23cd4I`

Note that it also works with playlists:

`yt:<youtube playlist url>`

For instance:

`yt:https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzCxunOM5WFLwpQbO6ytg35ex2b585WfG`